# Low variance gradient for entropy of gaussian mixture cross entropy

Tags: optimization, statistical-inference, monte-carlo, stochastic-approximation

Given $Z\sim$ Gaussian Mixture model:
$$p(z) = \sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i \cdot g_i(z) $$
with $g_i(z) = \mathcal{N}(z;\mu_i,\sigma^2_i),$ define $\phi = \{\mu_i,\sigma^2_i,\pi_i\}_{i=1}^n.$

I want to find a low variance estimate for the entropy $\nabla_\phi \mathcal{H}(q(z)).$ At least for the gradients with respect to $\mu_i,\sigma^2_i$ I was thinking of writing:

$$ \nabla \mathcal{H}(q(z)) = \sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i \cdot \nabla \mathbb{E_{Z\sim g_i(\cdot)}[\log p(z)]} $$
together with the $\epsilon$ reparametrization trick for each component $g_i(\cdot).$

Is there a better way of doing it, i.e. estimator with lower variance?

What would be the best way to compute derivatives with respect to the mixture weights? We could just have the same approach as above. In this case, would we know if this estimator has high variance?

How could I test this empirically?

Thanks!!!

Comment: what is $\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst, I'm pretty sure it's the entropy

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst edited. entropy indeed

Comment: if you give me some background I may be able to provide some insight